# Add tr element on even number

Tags: php, html

So I have a `<tr>` which I want to open `<tr>` and close `</tr>` every 2nd time

So I have tried this:

```
<?php $i = 0; foreach($blogs as $story): ?>
<?=(($i % 2) == 0) ? "<tr>" : null ?>
 <td>my stuff</td>
<?=(($i % 2) == 0) ? "</tr>" : null ?>
<?php ++$i; endforeach; ?>
```

But it adds every time, my need is to have one `<tr>` with two `<td>` inside

```
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
```

Comment: Your logic is flawed: This will always only either enclose exactly one`<td></td>` (for every even number i) or just output `<td>my stuff</td>`. See @nickn 's solution.

Comment: Look at the source code. Nickn's solution below is correct. What you think you are seeing in the rendered HTML is not what is actually happening. You have <td>...</td> cells that are not inside of <tr>...</tr> sets, making them appear like independent rows.

Comment: you should open yours loop with <tr> and close it with </tr>, then insert together </tr><tr> ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `<?=(($i % 2) == 1) ? "</tr>" : null ?>`  cause you have it `<?=(($i % 2) == 0) ? "</tr>" : null ?>`

Comment: Oops, that's stupid of me, you said 2nd. Never mind/

Comment: You can delete your answer if you feel it does not fit :)

Comment: @nickn You are correct. The first <td> needs a <tr> and it is even ($i==0). It does not need a </tr>. The second <td> has $i=1. It won't print <tr>, but it needs to print </tr>. The next <td> is $i=2, which is even, so it needs to print a <tr>, but not a </tr>.